# Python's asyncio works synchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm trying to leverage Python's new asyncio library to send asynchronous HTTP requests. I want to wait a few miliseconds (the `timeout` variable) before sending each request - but of course - send them all asynchronously and, not wait for a response after each request sent.

I'm doing something like the following:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_line(self, line, destination):
    print("Inside! line {} destination {}".format(line, destination))
    response = yield from aiohttp.request('POST', destination, data=line,
                               headers=tester.headers)
    print(response.status)
    return (yield from response.read())

@asyncio.coroutine
def send_data(self, filename, timeout):
    destination='foo'
    logging.log(logging.DEBUG, 'sending_data')
    with open(filename) as log_file:
        for line in log_file:
            try:
                json_event = json.loads(line)
            except ValueError as e:
                print("Error parsing json event")
            time.sleep(timeout)
            yield from asyncio.async(self.handle_line(json.dumps(json_event), destination))


loop=asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(send_data('foo.txt', 1))
```

The output that I am getting (by printing the 200 responses) looks like this code is running synchronously. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. You should use [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.sleep), not `time.sleep`, because the latter will block the event loop.
2. You shouldn't be using `yield from` after the `asyncio.async(self.handle_line(...))` call, because that will make the script block until the `self.handle_line` coroutine is complete, which means you don't end up doing anything concurrently; you process each line, wait for the processing to complete, then move on to the next line. Instead, you should run all the `asyncio.async` calls without waiting, save the `Task` objects returned to a list, and then use [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) to wait for them all to complete once you've started them all.

Putting that all together:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def handle_line(self, line, destination):
    print("Inside! line {} destination {}".format(line, destination))
    response = yield from aiohttp.request('POST', destination, data=line,
                               headers=tester.headers)
    print(response.status)
    return (yield from response.read())

@asyncio.coroutine
def send_data(self, filename, timeout):
    destination='foo'
    logging.log(logging.DEBUG, 'sending_data')
    tasks = []
    with open(filename) as log_file:
        for line in log_file:
            try:
                json_event = json.loads(line)
            except ValueError as e:
                print("Error parsing json event")
            yield from asyncio.sleep(timeout)
            tasks.append(asyncio.async(
                 self.handle_line(json.dumps(json_event), destination))
    yield from asyncio.wait(tasks)


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(send_data('foo.txt', 1))
```

Comment: hmm...
thank you.
but I am not sure it's exactly what I want though.
the yield from asyncio.sleep will wait a timeout before appending the task to the tasks list.
the yield from asyncio.wait will send all the requests concurrently.
I want them to be sent one after one with the timeout interval between each request. that code will not wait between each request. it will send them all at once.

Comment: @OhadBasan  The `yield from asyncio.sleep(timeout)` line will make the code wait `timeout` seconds between *starting* each task, not just between appending it to the task list. The task actually gets added to the event loop and starts is soon as you call `asyncio.async(task())`. You don't need to actually `yield from` the task for it to start execution.

Comment: @OhadBasan It helps to think of `yield from` not as _starting_ a coroutine, but rather as _waiting_ for its completion.